# Controle de concorrência em inserção no banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, webforms

Estou com um problema de controle de concorrência na inserção de dados de uma tabela. O cenário é o seguinte:

Existe uma tabela que registra dados diários de acordo com a requisição de usuários, e estes dados não podem ser duplicados. O controle de concorrência atual verifica se existe algum registro destes dados na tabela naquele dia, e caso exista, bloqueia a inserção.

O problema é que esta implementação está sendo ineficiente pois quando dois usuários clicam simultaneamente no botão, a verificação é feita simultaneamente (resultando em "Não existe dados no banco") e a inserção também, criando dados duplicados na tabela.

Como posso implementar um controle de concorrência sem a utilização de um lock na tabela, uma vez que esta tabela é constantemente utilizada e um lock provavelmente tornaria a transação mais lenta?

```
public void InserirFoo(Foo variavel, int id)
{
    var diaDeHoje = DateTime.Now;
    if (!VerificarInsercao(id, diaDeHoje))
    {
        contexto.FooDataSet.inserir(variavel);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private bool VerificarInsercao(int id, DateTime dataAtual)
{
    return contexto.FooDataSet.Any(e => e.id == id && e.dataInsercao == dataAtual); 
}
```

Comment: Coloque seu código que está fazendo isto.

Comment: Bigown. Pergunta editada!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usando escopo transacional. Assim:

```
public void InserirFoo(Foo variavel, int id)
{
    var diaDeHoje = DateTime.Now;
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
    {
        if (!VerificarInsercao(id, diaDeHoje))
        {
            contexto.FooDataSet.inserir(variavel);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Isto evita colisão, visto que duas transações não podem ser abertas na mesma operação ao mesmo tempo.

O suporte assíncrono existe a partir do .NET 4.5.2:

```
public async Task InserirFoo(Foo variavel, int id)
{
    var diaDeHoje = DateTime.Now;
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) 
    {
        if (!VerificarInsercao(id, diaDeHoje))
        {
            contexto.FooDataSet.inserir(variavel);
            await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que entendi, grosso modo você está experimentando o que se chama [race condition](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Em uma *race condition* você começa fazer uma operação e obtém algum resultado. Durante o processo ou logo ao final dele, algo muda e este estado não é mais válido, mas seu programa acha que é. Ou seja, quando você executa o `Any` no `FooDataSet`, ele não acha nada com aquelas características, mas quando executa o `SaveChanges`, já existe um dado no banco de dados com aquelas características, colocado por outro processo que tinha iniciado a execução antes ou foi mais rápido por alguma razão.

Não conheço bem a tecnologia que você está usando, mas posso dizer que o segredo é deixar o banco de dados lidar com isto. Mandar gravar e verificar se a operação foi bem sucedida ou não. Claro que o banco de dados precisa estar estruturado de forma que uma informação duplicada não consiga ser inserida. Desconheço e duvido que exista outra possibilidade de resolver isto.

[Esse artigo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/april/data-points-why-does-entity-framework-reinsert-existing-objects-into-my-database?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pode lhe ajudar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o lock do C#, basicamente ele bloqueia que outra pessoa acessa o código que está "LOCKADO" enquanto alguém já estiver lá.

```
object lockObject = new object();
public void DemoLock()
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        InsereRegistrosNaTabela();
    }
}
```

Comment: E como isto impede que outro processo atualize o banco de dados?