# Pesquisa de dados não commitados

Tags: c#, ado.net, transações

Estava fazendo uns testes com relação a transações e vi que se eu realizar uma pesquisa dos dados cadastrados e não comitados eles são retornados. No entity Framework isto não acontece, e pelo que eu pesquisei por tras dos panos ele trabalha com transações.

Alguem sabe como posso contornar esta situação:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["connNorthwind"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();
        var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        string productName = "tEST1";


        var commad1 = conn.CreateCommand();
        commad1.Transaction = transaction;

        var commad2 = conn.CreateCommand();
        commad2.Transaction = transaction;

        var commad3 = conn.CreateCommand();
        commad3.Transaction = transaction; 


        commad1.CommandText = "INSERT products(ProductName, Discontinued)VALUES ('" + productName + "', 'true')";
        commad1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        commad2.CommandText = "INSERT products(ProductName, Discontinued)VALUES ('" + productName + "', 'true')";
        commad2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        commad3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM products where ProductName like '%" + productName + "%'";
        var reader = commad3.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult);

        bool produtoExistente = false;
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            produtoExistente = true;
        }


        Assert.IsFalse(produtoExistente);
```

Answer (score 0):

Os dados aparecem porque você possivelmente utiliza a mesma conexão que abriu a transação para consultar, então é correto que apareçam.

[No Entity Framework, a transação não é por conexão, e sim por escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32299/controle-de-concorr%C3%AAncia-em-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-banco-de-dados/32371#32371). Isto porque é o Entity Framework que controla a(s) conexão(ões), e não o programador. Além disso, o escopo transacional usando MSDTC permite o uso de transações distribuídas, ideal para balanceamento de carga em sistemas grandes.

No caso do seu código, faltou ainda realizar ou um [`Commit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx) ou um [`Rollback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zayx5s0h(v=vs.110).aspx).