# Melhor prática para verificar se o módulo está sendo utilizado

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

A minha pergunta que talvez - espero que não - possa ser considerada como de opinião, é conceitual e até mesmo simples.

Na maioria das aplicações, trabalhamos com recursos que quando utilizados por diversos usuários ao mesmo tempo, podem causar algum problema na base de dados. Em minha aplicação, tenho eventos que disparam informações para duas, três e até mais tabelas e se caso houverem muitos usuários editando essas informações ao mesmo tempo, pode ocorrer alguma inconsistência.

Em geral nesses momentos, crio campos para armazenar o `id` do usuário que está adentrando o módulo e com isso, valido a inexistência de um `id` armazenado para liberar - ou não - a edição. Caso exista usuário editando e um novo tente acessar o módulo, exibo uma mensagem e dou ao mesmo a opção de prosseguir para a edição ou aguardar a finalização.
Se o usuário escolher prosseguir, troco o `id` armazenado pelo de tal usuário e invalido as alterações do primeiro usuário, pois antes de enviar as alterações, verifico se o mesmo possui `id` correspondente com o armazenado em tabela.

Como pode haver queda de sessão, queda de energia e outros fenômenos naturais - ou não - que impeçam o usuário de finalizar, limpo diariamente o campo que armazena o `id`.

Existe algum modelo que aplique mais segurança e/ou praticidade e/ou organização para tarefas desse tipo? Existe algum modo de trabalhar com isso sem necessitar da criação de campos que armazenam o `id` do usuário atual?

Comment: Na verdade existem dispositivos de controle de concorrência que evitam esses problemas, mas a resposta daria um texto grande. Havendo um tempo livre posso responder.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Ok, obrigado

Comment: Só tratar as concorrências, da uma olhada. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32299/controle-de-concorr%C3%AAncia-em-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Esperando a sua resposta hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tratar manualmente a concorrência em alterações de banco tentando garantir a integridade dos dados dá muito trabalho e geralmente não funciona direito.

A sua solução, por exemplo, tem esse problema de manter bloqueados registros que não estão mais sendo editados devido à queda da sessão e desistência do usuário.

## Garantindo a integridade dos dados

> A forma mais comum de tratar a concorrência é editando *offline* todo o conjunto de dados e mandando para o banco todas as alterações de uma vez, numa única  operação atômica, usando o **controle de concorrência otimista**, onde o primeiro usuário a enviar suas alterações ganha.

Em C# isso pode ser feito através de *Datasets* ou *Data tables* e *Data adapters*:

As alterações do usuário que precisam ser atômicas são feitas todas em memória, em *datatables*. Quando o usuário salva o trabalho, uma transação de banco de dados é iniciada, todas as alterações feitas nos *datatables* são submetidas de uma vez ao banco e a transação é commitada.

Através de comandos de UPDATE, INSERT e DELETE informados por você ou gerados automaticamente, o ADO.Net percebe se os registros foram alterados por outro usuário entre a obtenção deles e o salvamento no banco, e, se foi o caso, a transação é cancelada e o aplicativo informa o usuário. Você não precisa fazer nenhum bloqueio manual.

Isso se torna ainda mais simples com o uso de frameworks ORM como o *Entity Framework* ou *NHibernate*.

## Bloqueio para efeito de usabilidade

Você também pode querer fazer um bloqueio prévio a fim de que o usuário não perca tempo editando um registro que ele provavelmente não vai poder salvar porque já tem outro usuário editando.

Este tipo de bloqueio não deveria ser usado para tentar garantir integridade dos dados mas sim apenas como um recurso de usabilidade.

Por exemplo, eu trabalhei num projeto onde havia um grande volume de dados para serem processados por um grupo de usuários. Todos tinham o mesmo trabalho: processar cada registro, e o trabalho deveria ser dividido entre eles (cada um processava um conjunto diferente de registros).

A solução que implementamos foi: quando um usuário obtinha um registro para processá-lo (o processamento consistia em fazer algumas edições em uma coleção de registros), uma marcação era registrada no banco, informando que aquele conjunto de registros já estava sendo processado por algúem. Então o aplicativo não selecionava para processamento os registros que já estavam com a marcação.

A marcação por sua vez não era o id do usuário mas sim um *timestamp*, e o bloqueio expirava depois de um tempo (que era o tempo estimado que o usuário demorava para processar o registro).

Então, na verdade, em vez de selecionar registros não bloqueados, o aplicativo selecionava registros não bloqueados e também aqueles cujo bloqueio já havia expirado. Isso dispensa uma rotina para desbloquear registros cuja edição foi cancelada.

Veja que este bloqueio tinha o intuito apenas de melhorar a usabilidade, a técnica de concorrência otimista descrita acima é que garantia a integridade dos dados.

Answer (score 2):

No seu lugar, não faria bloqueio pelo banco, e sim usando uma *cache* distribuída, como por exemplo o [Redis](http://redis.io/).

[Aqui tem um tutorial de como usar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636730/Distributed-Caching-using-Redis). Ao invés de armazenar chaves de usuário, eu armazenaria chaves por módulo, ou por tela, ou até por *Action* no caso de uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC.

As vantagens são várias. Você pode renovar as chaves caso um usuário ainda esteja editando a tela, ou ainda pode retirar o direito dele de realizar a edição caso tenha demorado demais.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não deixo/deixaria as tabelas alocadas até o usuário pensar em clicar em algum lugar para desaloca-las, pelo menos nunca passei por uma situação onde esse caso era a única alternativa.

Eu faço o seguinte, deixo o usuario fazer em tela as alterações que ele deseja, quando ele finalizar na tela mando tudo p/ bando de dados, dai começo a fazer as devidas locações, faço um **[LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)** nas tabelas antes de começar a fazer todas as alterações quando estas são dependentes de chaves em outras tabelas