# Concorrência Server ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, servidor, wcf, silverlight

Tenho uma aplicação Silverlight, que acessa um serviço em WCF. Nessa aplicação tenho um método **SalvarNotaFiscal()**. Esse método chama um método **ValidarNotaFiscal** que verifica se já existe uma nota fiscal com o número e série informados. Esse método SalvarNotaFiscal é bem grande, pois executa várias rotinas.

Ocorreu do cliente clicar várias vezes nesse botão, e foram lançadas 6 notas com o mesmo número no sistema; o cenário foi esse acredito, pois não teria outra forma de duplicar essas notas se existe a validação.

Acredito que o ASP.NET atende as requisições em paralelo, o que faz sentido para mim, pois pode haver vários usuários simultâneos e o servidor precisa atender todos ao mesmo tempo.

Quanto ao meu problema no Silverlight, já tentei desabilitar o botão quando é clicado e habilitar no retorno callback, mas não tem funcionado.

```
public void Salvar()
{
  btnSalvar.IsEnabled = false; 
  NotaFiscalClient objSvcNotaFiscal = new NotaFiscalClient();
  objSvcNotaFiscal.SalvarNotaFiscalAsync(this.objNotaFiscal);
  objSvcNotaFiscal.SalvarNotaFiscalCompleted += (s, e) =>
       btnSalvar.IsEnabled = true;         
  };
}
```

Comment: Qual código dentro de SalvarNotaFiscalAsync() ? coloca aí

Comment: O código é gigantesco, chama vários métodos, integra com webservices, e não posso postar por regras de privacidade da empresa. Esse bloco acima ainda posso. A validação funciona normal em um cenário normal. O problema é usuário que fica clicando várias vezes no botão. Inclusive a tela é congelada, mas até ela congelar dá tempo pelo jeito de ser enviada várias requisições iguais.

Comment: Então, basta você colocar um semáforo que creio que resolva seu problema

Comment: O que seria isso na prática?

Comment: Da uma olhada, isso vai bloquear outra inserção ENQUANTO outra nao acaba. http://www.bufaloinfo.com.br/ExibeNoticias.aspx?entryid=7326980343120390112

Comment: Você pode fazer isso com TransactionScope http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32299/controle-de-concorr%C3%AAncia-em-inser%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: isso ai é minha pergunta. talvez convenha eu fechar o post

Answer (score 0):

Sim, as requisições HTTP ocorrem em paralelo.

É possível bloquear que isso ocorra de diversos modos...

Primeiro comece bloqueando o usuário de apertar o botão várias vezes, antes que uma solicitação seja concluída... (basta colocar um LOCK simples no método **Salvar** que já deve resolver!)

Já em relação a múltiplos usuários gerando a nota com mesmo número, você terá que fazer o tratamento no back-end (WCF), o mais fácil é também através da instrução [LOCK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), porém somente se você tem um único servidor executando um único processo do WCF irá funcionar!

Caso o webservice esteja executando através de vários processos simultâneos, você pode usar uma [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) para garantir o acesso único a um trecho do código (ou ao método inteiro, no seu caso)

Lembrando que tanto a instrulção LOCK, como a utilização da classe Mutex, você precisa criar uma lógica que só permita que uma nota por vez entre no processo de acordo com o número da nota e não generalizado, se não você terá uma fila de notas a processar, sendo uma por vez, causando lentidão aos usuários.

Caso o seu back-end (WCF) esteja distribuido (em vários servidores, balanceamento de carga, failover, etc) você não irá conseguir sucesso só com um LOCK/MUTEX, você irá precisar criar um sistema em que irá existir um servidor único de controle de locks e então efetuar o lock por lá, ou melhor, você pode fazer isso usando um banco de dados (SQL) ou até mesmo o Redis.
Numa solução melhor para este cenário seria implementar um sistema de mensageria (MSMQ ou Redis) onde apenas um host seria responsável por processar as notas, e os outros apenas executando as outras tarefas...