# Uso Concorrente em Aplicações Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou começando a estudar programação em asp.net mvc (e tentando seguir o DDD) e, com isso, me surgiu uma dúvida em relação ao uso concorrente: O Asp.net já realiza esse controle para mim ou eu é quem devo controlar isso com Threads em tudo quanto é método do meu sistema (Controllers, acesso a dados, camada de application, etc)?

Comment: Raphael, Boa tarde Sugiro que leia o artigo do link abaixo, que trata sobre Domain Driven Design (DDD) e como utilizá-lo no .NET Framework http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-ddd-em-net/32724

Comment: Obrigado JeordaneBatista!  muito bom o artigo, mas é que estou mais em dúvida é ao uso concorrente mesmo.

Comment: Depende da forma que está programando, se estiver criando objeto statics, deverá fazer este controle.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Controle de concorrência em inserção no banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32299/controle-de-concorr%c3%aancia-em-inser%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-banco-de-dados)

Comment: O que exatamente você tem dúvida no controle de concorrência? As chamadas nas controllers/actions? Isso o asp.net controla e o IIS também, agora coisas de código (como objetos e listas em memória) você deve implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta nao eh muito especifica, vou tentar responder levando em conta o que voce mais citou (DDD e DAL).

Existe o controle de concorrencia a nivel de `request`, isto é, requests simultaneos tem sua própria memória como um sandbox, eles não dividem **a maioria** dos estados. Um exemplo de objeto que é dividido é sessão.

Como voce falou mais com foco em DDD e acesso a dados (imagino que seja o banco), você que tem que fazer o controle.
Suponha que voce ta usando o `EntityFramework`, voce pode ter requests simultaneos mexendo no mesmo dado, e isso pode dar problema.

Exemplo: um sistema de reserva, onde o usuario A pode estar com a janela de assentos aberta, pensando onde vai sentar. Enquanto isso, o usuario B tambem chega nessa tela e escolhe o assento 1. Coincidentemente, o usuario A tambem escolhe o assento 1 e dispara o request junto com usuario B, de modo que os 2 requests chegam no servidor juntos. Nesse momento, se seu codigo nao tratar concorrencia e simplesmente executar `User.MakeReservation(1)` para ambos usuarios, voce vai ter perda de dados.

Existem varias maneiras de lidar com isso, como a concorrencia pessimista e a otimista.

A nivel de threads e tudo mais, cada request, na maioria das vezes, vai ter o seu espaco, e dentro desse espaco voce tem que tratar concorrencias desse tipo.